# Elementor page builder shortcode issue

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, elementor

I'm facing a weird  problem when using the Elementor Wordpress Page Builder.

After creating a custom shortcode and inserting it into any page position, it also shows up at the top of the page, but only in Edit mode.

Top of the page:

[image: Top of the page]

Place where I want to insert shortcode:

[image: place where i want to insert shortcode]

Comment: `function test_shortcodes()
{
    return 'Shortcodes are working!';
}
add_shortcode('test_shortcodes', 'test_shortcodes');`
I have added this function in Twenty Seventeen template `function.php` file. Use Elementor shortcode widget to display my `[test_shortcodes]`. It shows in elementor but not working on live page.

Answer (score 10):

This answer on an unrelated site helped me solve this Elementor issue. https://wp-types.com/forums/topic/shortcode-output-showing-up-in-the-wrong-place/

I just had to include `ob_start();` and `$content = ob_get_clean(); return $content;` in my function. Here is what it looks like:

```
function custom_author_link_function() {
        ob_start();

        coauthors_posts_links();

        $content = ob_get_clean();
        return $content;
}
add_shortcode('custom_author_link', 'custom_author_link_function');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my working example:

```
  function name_it( ){
        ob_start();

        function_name();

        $content = ob_get_clean();
        return $content;
   return function_name();
}
add_shortcode( 'shortcode_name', 'name_it' );
```

Just look at **function_name();** and **return function_name();** lines to avoid errors.